# How to get popup window in MVC using Javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnpopup2').click(function () {

        jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#SearchPopupWindow1').load("/Service/ServiceList",
                function (response, status, xhr) {
                    $('#SearchPopupWindow1').dialog('open');
               });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open dialog after load complete.

**Updated code**

```
$('#btnpopup2').click(function () {

        jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#SearchPopupWindow1').load("/Service/ServiceList").dialog('open');

   });
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `noConflict()` in this snippet? I think it will be more confusing that useful.